# Visual Studio not Autocompleting JS Function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete

Autocomplete used to work on this function (when it had fewer parameters):

```
function player(firstName, lastName, hometownCity, hometownState, highSchoolName, otherAccountName, redshirted, transferred, hometownZip, hometownCountry, bioLink, collegeYear, HighSchoolGradYear, Position, Number, HeightFeet, HeightInches, Weight, Gender, PlayerId) {
this.FirstName = ko.observable(firstName);
this.LastName =  ko.observable(lastName);
this.HometownCity =  ko.observable(hometownCity);
this.HometownState =  ko.observable(hometownState);
this.Name_HighSchool =  ko.observable(highSchoolName);
this.Name_OtherAccount =  ko.observable(otherAccountName);
this.Redshirted =  ko.observable(redshirted);
this.Transferred =  ko.observable(transferred);
this.HometownZip =  ko.observable(hometownZip);
this.HometownCountry =  ko.observable(hometownCountry);
this.BioLink =  ko.observable(bioLink);
this.CollegeYear =  ko.observable(collegeYear);
this.HighSchoolGradYear =  ko.observable(HighSchoolGradYear);
this.Position =  ko.observable(Position);
this.Number =  ko.observable(Number);
this.HeightFeet =  ko.observable(HeightFeet);
this.HeightInches =  ko.observable(HeightInches);
this.Weight =  ko.observable(Weight);
this.Gender = ko.observable(Gender);
this.PlayerId = PlayerId;
}
```

And still works on this function (so I know autocomplete is enabled):

```
function stuff(thing) {
this.thing = thing;
}
```

Neither autocomplete on `var p = new player(...)` nor `p.Fir....` works.

Is there a limit to function size with autocomplete?

Thanks!